# Pokemon Japanese Pocket monster cards?

Tags: pokemon

[image: Unknown pocket monster card back]

[image: Twelve pocket monster cards in a square]

Does anyone know what kind of cards these are?

Comment: Looks like a particular style of trading card to me. It'll be hard to track down what it is specifically since I expect most searches to give results for the TCG, but good luck!

Answer (score 4):

They are Topsun Pokemon cards from 1997. There was also a 1995 set of Topsun cards, which is more common. They came from Bandai vending machines in a gum and card pack.

There is a video of someone opening a pack [on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ddxzmr7lsu4)

There are also a number of listings [on eBay](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=TOPSUN+pokemon+card+1997)